# MATLAB code, B = repmat(A, [1 1 1 13]). When I use the python equivalent numpy.matlib.repmat, I am not getting the desired result

Tags: python, matlab

A 3-D matrix A has dimensions (181, 33, 65). The repmat function does the above operation and returns a 4-D matrix B of dimensions (181, 33, 65, 13). I tried in several ways in Python but was unsuccessful. Could someone suggest me a quick answer?

Comment: You also have [numpy.matlib.repmat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matlib.repmat.html)

Comment: numpy.matlib.repmat takes in only 3 arguments, while in the code I have 5 arguments.

Comment: @Nirmal your code has 2 arguments, separated by a coma.